# Design input in select Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

What I'm looking for is whether there is a bootstrap model in select input that has the arrow + background on the right.

[link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MyqxMe)

**CODE HTML:**

```
<div class="bootstrap-select input-group  ">
  <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="my_select_label" class="form-control ">
  <input type="hidden" name="my_select" value="">
  <div class="input-group-btn open">
    <button tabindex="-1" type="button" class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle active">
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul tabindex="-1" class="pull-right dropdown-menu warning">
      <li class="active">
        <a tabindex="-1" href=""></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a tabindex="-1" href="Hydrogen">Hydrogen</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a tabindex="-1" href="Helium">Helium</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a tabindex="-1" href="Lithium">Lithium</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a tabindex="-1" href="Beryllium">Beryllium</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a tabindex="-1" href="Boron">Boron</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a tabindex="-1" href="Carbon">Carbon</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a tabindex="-1" href="Nitrogen">Nitrogen</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I managed to find this model but has two problems:

1.is always open ... not going to click

2.I want to have a structure like the following...(currently is the type list)

```
<select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
```

Does anyone know of an example that meet the above condition?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe someone will have better way, but in the meantime you can try to use :before like this

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-6 mySelect">
        <select class="form-control">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
        </select>    
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.mySelect {position: relative}
.mySelect select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    background-color:transparent;
    position:relative;
    z-index:5;
}
.mySelect:before {
    content: "\f078";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-size:16px;
    width: 34px;
    height: 34px;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:15px;
    background-color:orange;
    border-radius:0 4px 4px 0;
    line-height:34px;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
}
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/19886/)**

Answer (score 0):

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns

I'm wondering that you import the jquery CDN into your source code on the <head> tag?

There may be some problems if you don't import jquery on you site.

And you should edit your <button> tags into like this code.

```
<button tabindex="-1" type="button" class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle active" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
```

For the 2 problem, This may help you.

https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/